# How to disable a button programatically?

Tags: objective-c, uibutton

I have two text fields and a button.
My goal is to have that button enabled only when both text fields have some text in.

This is what I do:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    .....
    self.btnLogIn.enabled=NO;
}
```

I programatically create the text fields, this is the code:

```
UITextField *textField = [[UITextField alloc] init];
......
textField.delegate=self;
[textField addTarget:self action:@selector(textChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];
```

This is the event handler:

```
-(void)textChanged:(UITextField *)textField
{
    UITextField *txtPassword = (UITextField *)[self.view viewWithTag:102];
    UITextField *txtUsername = (UITextField *)[self.view viewWithTag:101];
    if([txtPassword.text length]>0 && [txtUsername.text length]>0)
    {
        self.btnLogIn.enabled=YES;
    }
    else
    {
        self.btnLogIn.enabled=NO;
    }
}
```

I put three breakpoints:

- self.btnLogIn.enabled=NO; (in viewDidLoad)
- self.btnLogIn.enabled=YES; (in textChanged)
- self.btnLogIn.enabled=NO; (in textChanged)

When I run the app, it hits all the brakpoints but the button is still enabled.

If I uncheck Enabled from the designer, it is always disabled.

What am I doing wrong?

LE: I dragged the button in the implementation file to create the outlet, this is the code:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *btnLogIn;
```

Comment: Have you setup the outlet so you can use the button in your code?

Comment: Did you correctly connect to button outlet in IB?

Comment: I dragged it in the implementation and assigned it a name(btnLogin), do I have to do anything else? It seems I have to do the reverse also, drag the button from the implementation file on the button from the designer. Strange. Can you add this comment as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Check that it is connected (breakpoint and check the variable of use `NSLog`)

Comment: On the lines where you change the enabled property, is btnLogIn *not* `nil`?

Comment: I did what I said in the comment above and now it works. Can you please explain me exactly why does that happen in an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: @user2611691 I'm confused: wasn't what you said in the comment above is the same thing that you said in the question, when you said that it did not work?

Comment: The first time you tried to make the link it apparently didn't "take", for whatever reason.  You can always examine the links in IB to make sure they're good, after you do the dragging.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: Nope, what was missing in the first place, was the connection from the implementation to the designer, I was only creating the outlet but not connecting it( this is what Wain explained to me )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure that the outlet is both created and connected. It isn't enough to just create the outlet in the code, you need to connect it too. When you drag out a connection from the XIB to the code it creates the outlet for you and should connect it, but check that it does. It's also possible that you accidentally undid part of the change or broke the connection. Debugging to check that the variable is not `nil` at runtime is also a first port of call.

Answer (score 0):

Provided you have outlets and the delegate of both text fields is set:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField 
  shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range 
              replacementString:(NSString *)string {

   NSString *completeText = 
         [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range
                                                 withString:string];
   self.button.enabled = completeText.length && 
        textField == firstTextField ?
              otherTextField.length : 
              firstTextField.length;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you validate the text field by using :

```
        if(txtPassword.text >0 && txtUsername.text >0){

// Code here for login process
    }

else{

    // Code here to inform user nothing has been entered for example a UIAlert
}
```

or Maybe Use:

```
       if(txtPassword.text == nil && txtUsername.text == nil){
            // Code here to inform user nothing has been entered for example a UIAlert
    }

else{

// Code here for login process

}
```

plus instead of: `self.btnLogIn.enabled=NO;` Could you not just use `btnLogIn.UserInteractionEnabled = NO;` and then set it back to `btnLogIn.UserInteractionEnabled = YES;` if needed